# Matching extended regular expressions in POSIX Shell

Tags: shell, unix, posix

I think I have a really simple question but i can't figure out the answer.
I have this code
`[[ "${file_name}" = ${regex} ]] && continue`
POSIX version does not  support this [[ ]] pattern... Basically what this line does is. If name of the file matches the Extended regular expression, it skips my loop. Is there a way in POSIX norm to do this same thing on one line? or is there any other way to have a word and compare it with E regular expression?
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Do you care if it's extended regex? For basic expression you can use `expr`. But there are tools: `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, `grep -E`.

Comment: Did you mean  `[[ "${file_name}" =~ ${regex} ]]`?

Comment: @Shawn yes i meant =~ ... sory misstyped there

Comment: @KamilCuk yes i need it to work with extended regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`grep -E`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html):

```
if grep -qE "$regex" "$file_name"; then
```

If you want to match the content of the variable `file_name`, pipe it to `grep`:

```
if printf "%s\n" "$file_name" | grep -qE "$regex"; then
```

Comment: Does this need a full path in variable $file_name?

Comment: No. Strange question, why? [Pathname resolution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) `If the pathname does not begin with a slash, the predecessor of the first filename of the pathname shall be taken to be the current working directory of the process (such pathnames are referred to as "relative pathnames")`.

Comment: ok my code looks like this 
`for file in "$1"/*
do
  file_name=$(basename "$file")
  if grep -qe "$regex" "$file_name" && [ $N_CH -eq 0 ]; then
     continue
`
problem is... it never jumps in to that IF statement... N_CH is just a value 0 or 1... it is condition for this to work

Comment: Please do not use never backticks \`. Use `$(...)` instead. Och right, you want to match filename against the regex, not file content, right?

Comment: Then create an [MCVE]. Post sample input, folder structure, file content, the content of `N_CH` variable and all the information needed to reproduce the problem you are getting, including input if any, output from your script and output you expect to get.

Comment: Omg it's working! :D thank you so much! that thing with piping is great!